# Change the value of an label using innerText Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am trying to change the text value of an label inside an li inside an ul.

So:

HTML and JS

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("hs-error-msgs inputs-list").innerText = "Bitte füllen Sie dieses Pflichtfeld aus!";
```

```html
<ul class="hs-error-msgs inputs-list" style="display:block;" role="alert" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.3">
  <li data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.3.$0"> <label data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.3.$0.0">Please complete this required field. </label> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an Element Collection

Comment: I know, but how is possible to change the value of the text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) returns a collection. You could take the first element of this collection and then select `label` within it with for example another collection method [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName).

```js
var ul = document.getElementsByClassName("hs-error-msgs inputs-list")[0]
var label = ul.getElementsByTagName('label')[0]

label.innerText = "Bitte füllen Sie dieses Pflichtfeld aus!";
```

```html
<ul class="hs-error-msgs inputs-list" style="display:block;" role="alert" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.3">
  <li data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.3.$0"> <label data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.3.$0.0">Please complete this required field. </label> </li>
</ul>
```

However way more convenient method for this is [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```js
var label = document.querySelector(".hs-error-msgs.inputs-list label")

label.innerText = "Bitte füllen Sie dieses Pflichtfeld aus!";
```

```html
<ul class="hs-error-msgs inputs-list" style="display:block;" role="alert" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.3">
  <li data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.3.$0"> <label data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.3.$0.0">Please complete this required field. </label> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. But now I need to use in the other. How can I use querySelectorAll properly?

Comment: @LuisFilipeEscobar `querySelectorAll` is a collection. So you need to iterate. `var labels = document.querySelectorAll(".hs-error-msgs.inputs-list label"); for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) { labels[i].innerHTML = '....' }`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the `label`, use `querySelector`

```
var text = "Bitte füllen Sie dieses Pflichtfeld aus!";
document.querySelector( ".hs-error-msgs inputs-list li label").innerText = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelector` to get a single item in one line.

```
document.querySelector(".hs-error-msgs.inputs-list label").innerText = "Bitte füllen Sie dieses Pflichtfeld aus!";
```

This will select a single label from inside the element with your specified classes. If you have multiple items, use `querySelectorAll` and iterate with a for loop.